# R error in connection to host

Tags: r

I have installed R 3.0.2 and package `KEGGREST`. While using it's command, I get the following error

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to
>   host

I can very well install package from internet after using --internet2 option, which uses proxy details from Internet explorer.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly what command did you enter?

Answer (score 6):

httr uses a different method to connect to the internet: you need to explicitly set the proxy using the following command:

`set_config(use_proxy(url='your.proxy.url',port,username,password))`

See

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/httr/docs/use_proxy

[Solution. How to install_github when there is a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy)

For more details