# Seach website for phrase in R

Tags: r, scrape, bubble-chart

I'd like to understand what applications of machine learning are being developed by the US federal government.  The federal government maintains the website [FedBizOps](https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list) that contains contracts.  The web site can be searched for a phrase, e.g. "machine learning", and a date range, e.g. "last 365 days" to find relevant contracts.  The resulting search produces links that contain a contract summary.

I'd like to be able to pull the contract summaries, given a search term and a date range, from this site.

Is there any way I can scrape the browser rendered data in to R? A similar question [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330393/scraping-javascript-generated-data) on web scraping, but I don't know how to change the date range.

Once the information is pulled into R, I'd like to organize the summaries with a bubble chart of key phrases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may look like a site that uses XHR via javascript to retrieve the URL contents, but it's not. It's just a plain web site that can easily be scraped via standard `rvest` & `xml2` calls like `html_session` and `read_html`. It *does* keep the `Location:` URL the same, so it kinda looks like XHR even thought it's not.

However, this is a `<form>`-based site, which means you could be generous to the community and write an R wrapper for the "hidden" API and possibly donate it to rOpenSci.

To that end, I used the `curlconverter` package on the "Copy as cURL" content from the `POST` request and it provided all the form fields (which seem to map to most — if not all — of the fields on the *advanced search* page):

```
library(curlconverter)

make_req(straighten())[[1]] -> req

httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list", 
    httr::add_headers(Pragma = "no-cache", 
        Origin = "https://www.fbo.gov", 
        `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate, br", 
        `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
        `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` = "1", 
        `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.41 Safari/537.36", 
        Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
        `Cache-Control` = "no-cache", 
        Referer = "https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list", 
        Connection = "keep-alive", 
        DNT = "1"), httr::set_cookies(PHPSESSID = "32efd3be67d43758adcc891c6f6814c4", 
        sympcsm_cookies_enabled = "1", 
        BALANCEID = "balancer.172.16.121.7"), 
    body = list(`dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][keywords]` = "machine+learning", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][_posted_date]` = "365", 
        search_filters = "search", 
        `_____dummy` = "dnf_", 
        so_form_prefix = "dnf_", 
        dnf_opt_action = "search", 
        dnf_opt_template = "VVY2VDwtojnPpnGoobtUdzXxVYcDLoQW1MDkvvEnorFrm5k54q2OU09aaqzsSe6m", 
        dnf_opt_template_dir = "Pje8OihulaLVPaQ+C+xSxrG6WrxuiBuGRpBBjyvqt1KAkN/anUTlMWIUZ8ga9kY+", 
        dnf_opt_subform_template = "qNIkz4cr9hY8zJ01/MDSEGF719zd85B9", 
        dnf_opt_finalize = "0", 
        dnf_opt_mode = "update", 
        dnf_opt_target = "", dnf_opt_validate = "1", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][dnf_class_name]` = "procurement_notice", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][notice_id]` = "63ae1a97e9a5a9618fd541d900762e32", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][posted]` = "", 
        `autocomplete_input_dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]` = "", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]` = "", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][zipstate]` = "", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][procurement_type][]` = "", 
        `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][set_aside][]` = "", 
        mode = "list"), encode = "form")
```

`curlconverter` adds the `httr::` prefixes to the various functions since you can actually use `req()` to make the request. It's a bona-fide R function.

However, most of the data being passed in is browser "cruft" and can be trimmed down a bit and moved into a `POST` request:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

POST(url = "https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list", 
     add_headers(Origin = "https://www.fbo.gov", 
                 Referer = "https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list"), 
     set_cookies(PHPSESSID = "32efd3be67d43758adcc891c6f6814c4", 
                 sympcsm_cookies_enabled = "1", 
                 BALANCEID = "balancer.172.16.121.7"), 
     body = list(`dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][keywords]` = "machine+learning", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][_posted_date]` = "365", 
                 search_filters = "search", 
                 `_____dummy` = "dnf_", 
                 so_form_prefix = "dnf_", 
                 dnf_opt_action = "search", 
                 dnf_opt_template = "VVY2VDwtojnPpnGoobtUdzXxVYcDLoQW1MDkvvEnorFrm5k54q2OU09aaqzsSe6m", 
                 dnf_opt_template_dir = "Pje8OihulaLVPaQ+C+xSxrG6WrxuiBuGRpBBjyvqt1KAkN/anUTlMWIUZ8ga9kY+", 
                 dnf_opt_subform_template = "qNIkz4cr9hY8zJ01/MDSEGF719zd85B9", 
                 dnf_opt_finalize = "0", 
                 dnf_opt_mode = "update", 
                 dnf_opt_target = "", dnf_opt_validate = "1", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][dnf_class_name]` = "procurement_notice", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][notice_id]` = "63ae1a97e9a5a9618fd541d900762e32", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][posted]` = "", 
                 `autocomplete_input_dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]` = "", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][agency]` = "", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][zipstate]` = "", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][procurement_type][]` = "", 
                 `dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][set_aside][]` = "",
                 mode="list"), 
     encode = "form") -> res
```

This portion:

```
     set_cookies(PHPSESSID = "32efd3be67d43758adcc891c6f6814c4", 
                 sympcsm_cookies_enabled = "1", 
                 BALANCEID = "balancer.172.16.121.7")
```

makes me think you should use `html_session` or `GET` at least once on the main URL to establish those cookies in the cached `curl` handler (which will be created & maintained automagically for you).

The `add_headers()` bit may also not be necessary but that's an exercise left for the reader.

You can find the table you're looking for via:

```
content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("table.list") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  dplyr::glimpse()
## Observations: 20
## Variables: 4
## $ Opportunity            <chr> "NSN: 1650-01-074-1054; FILTER ELEMENT, FLUID; WSIC: L SP...
## $ Agency/Office/Location <chr> "Defense Logistics Agency DLA Acquisition LocationsDLA Av...
## $ Type /  Set-aside      <chr> "Presolicitation", "Presolicitation", "Award", "Award", "...
## $ Posted On              <chr> "Sep 28, 2016", "Sep 28, 2016", "Sep 28, 2016", "Sep 28, ...
```

There's an indicator on the page saying these are results *"1 - 20 of 2008"*. You need to scrape that as well and deal with the paginated results. This is also left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Note, if you get the error curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) Couldn't connect to server, it is solved at link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641808/r-error-in-connection-to-host.

Comment: Seems the search string "machine+learning" should be put in quotes as '"machine learning"', to find the 21 contracts that contain the phrase "machine learning", instead of the 2008 contracts.   How to follow the link to the contract listing? Or get the 21st example on the next page?

Comment: By actually reading up on how to scrape web pages and instrument scraping with R tools. You have to be willing to do _some_ work. And, I agree about the quotes for the search term, but that's a site-specific thing and this isn't my assignment, so I provided this answer primarily for others who are trying to find similar solutions since I was wary this would turn into a "write this scraping for me" question.