# Issue setting up my shinyapps.io + AUTHORIZE ACCOUNT + time out port 443

Tags: shiny

I am setting up my shinyapps.io [here](https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/dashboard)

I can now get it to install using `devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')` but before that I had to set my proxy in [Rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy/17795482#comment44974313_17795482)

But now I cannot Authorise the account. Any one else get here? is this still a proxy issue?

```
> shinyapps::setAccountInfo(name='username', token='<TOKEN>',secret='')
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to api.shinyapps.io port 443: Timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

Please read

```
library(shinyapps)
?shinyappsProxies
?shinyappsOptions
```

It worked via my enterprise proxy with the RCUrl option as follows:

```
options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "http://user:pwd@proxy:port"))
options(shinyapps.http = "rcurl")
```