# How to connect to shinyapps with a firewall installed?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to connect to shinyapps via Rstudio using the setAccountInfo function in the rsconnect package:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='MYACCOUNTNAME',
          token='TOKEN',
          secret='<SECRET>')
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>     Failed to connect to api.shinyapps.io port 443: Timed out

I am in my office PC and one of the more likely problems would be the firewall of the enterprise, so **my questions would be**:

1. Is there a way to workaround this problem and connect anyway?
2. If not, what would be the instruction I would have to give the IT department to be capable of connecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following options should help you see whats happening:

```
library(rsconnect)
options(rsconnect.http.trace = TRUE, rsconnect.error.trace = TRUE, rsconnect.http.verbose = TRUE)
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='MYACCOUNTNAME',
      token='TOKEN',
      secret='<SECRET>')
```

By running this you should see what IP addresses rsconnect is trying to use. Try adding this to a whitelist for your firewall.
If this doesn't work it may be a proxy issue. [Issue setting up my shinyapps.io + AUTHORIZE ACCOUNT + time out port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418180/issue-setting-up-my-shinyapps-io-authorize-account-time-out-port-443) This should help set up a proxy in rStudio.

Comment: Your answer really helped me to realize I was behind a proxy, I followed the instructions written here: [Rstudio help](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226804027-Deploying-to-shinyapps-io-when-behind-a-proxy) and managed to connect. Thanks!