# r install_github("timelyportfolio/sunburstR") proxy and manual install

Tags: r, github, install.packages

sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows XP (build 2600) Service Pack 3

I'm having issues installing this package directly from github. Error below. Maybe this is the solution [Solution. How to install_github when there is a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy) but where do I find the relevant inputs url="18.91.12.23", port=8080, username="user",password="password". I'm not an expert in R by any means but this install is killing me.

```
.libPaths("U:/Packages")
 library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/sunburstR")
Downloading GitHub repo timelyportfolio/sunburstR@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Couldn't resolve host name
```

I then try to download the zip file and use the manual R studio install, however this is not working either.

```
install.packages("~/Packages/sunburstR-master.zip", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘U:/Packages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
library(sunburstR)
Error in library(sunburstR) : there is no package called ‘sunburstR’
```

The file in the folder and the zip file extracts the folder after I run the install packages but its not working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `devtools` installed already, try installing from source using `devtools::install`.

Try this:

```
library(devtools)
install("~/Packages/sunburstR-master.zip")
```

And see if the install works. Otherwise, you can unzip the package to get the source files and try again

```
library(devtools)
install("<Path_to_sunburstR>")
```

Also, since you are working on Windows, make sure you have [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed.