# R installation Error in due to proxy settings

Tags: r

I have installed latest RStudio and R 3.2.5 versions. My internet has a proxy setting. Whenever I try to install packages from installer it doesn't show me suggestions list. Then I try installing those by downloading its .zip files. But some of the packages like Shiny,rpivotTable don't get installed and show the following error .....

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘digest’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

I tried installing "digest" package too.. But it shows

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'digest_0.6.9 (4)/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Then I changed the repositories while installing digest but gave me another error stating..

```
    > install.packages("C:/Users/m76analytics/Downloads/digest_0.6.9 (4).zip", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "win.binary")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required'
```

I need some help .. I am stuck everywhere....

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy

Comment: if (!require("devtools")) install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)              I ran above code ... But it still gives me an error saying                          Loading required package: devtools
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘digest’
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required'

Comment: I have changed my proxy settings too ...

Comment: You already download the digest.zip package. You can install it manually by: http://outmodedbonsai.sourceforge.net/InstallingLocalRPackages.html

Comment: Oh. .Okay ..got it ..thanks man.....