# Trying to install CoreNLP in R but getting error (New in R)

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp

Hello I'm trying to install coreNLP packege from github using devtool but unbale to do so. getting this error-

> devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")
>   Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
>     Couldn't connect to server"

help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe that is a [proxy issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy)?

Comment: Why don't you directly install from CRAN repo ? Use  install.packages("coreNLP")