# Installation package r2excel R package

Tags: r, package

I would like to install the package `r2excel`. 
Unfortunately, I can't do that because of my proxy.
So, I have to obtain `r2excel.tar.gz` to install my package.

Could you help me?

Of course I tried:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/r2excel")
library(r2excel)
```

but it isn't working as I said because of my proxy...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [You can get `install_github` to use your proxy settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17795482/1968).

Comment: The code above requires the rJava package to have been installed, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RStudio,

Go to the Packages tab, click the Install button, and change `"Install from:"` to `Package Archive File (.tgz; .tar.gz)`