# Linux: error in curl - Can't install R-packages with devtools::install_github()

Tags: r, linux, git, leaflet

I want to install the R-package Leaflet on my R-server(linux) from GitHub because it is more up-to-date than the current CRAN-version. I’m using the following R-script to do this:

```
library(httr)
library(devtools)

set_config(use_proxy(url = "xxx", port = xxxx))
devtools::install_github("rstudio/leaflet")
```

But it is showing the following error:

> ```
> if(!require('devtools')) install.packages('devtools')
> Loading required package: devtools
> devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')
> Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/leaflet@master
> from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/leaflet/zipball/master
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
>   Couldn't connect to server
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... request_fetch -> request_fetch.write_memory -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
> Execution halted
> ```

When I do install packages from CRAN, there are no issues at all. But I need the newest version of Leaflet which is only at GitHub...

Is there a solution to fix this? Is it because I'm using a proxy?

Regards,

Joris

Comment: Do you need to use the `set_config()`-function? It might be the case that the proxy is configured incorrectly...

Comment: According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy. But I'm still not sure this error is because of proxy...