# Install rword2vec R package from github

Tags: r, package, word2vec

I am a new R programmer, and I would like to use rword2vec package which is described here : [https://github.com/mukul13/rword2vec](https://houseofstones.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/automatic-cleaning-of-messy-text-data/)

I find that this package is really interesting .
As I am new R used, I don't know how to use it, to install it.

When I try to install it on my windows PC, I get this message :

```
install_github("mukul13/rword2vec")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name
>
```

Thank you for your help

Bests,

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy)?

Comment: Thank You Roman, How can I check this, I am using the PC of my company..