# unable to download packages in R from Github under proxy LAN connection:

Tags: r, github, proxy, installation, lan

I am unable to download packages from github using links devtool and github commands: 
Although other packages available in the install package of CRAN gets downloaded easily without any problem. i want to install EBImage packages from https://github.com/aoles/EBImage.git
It is only that i am unable to download from Github website.Please note the website in not blocked by authority. i am using R 3.6 version on 64bit windows 10 
How do i solve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There is probably already a solution here for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17795482/727089

Comment: i tried but ddnt work:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy/17795482#17795482

Comment: the proxy got accepted but It doesn't work..Till Devtools its ok..But  still not able to download.

Comment: Do you get the same error message as before?

Comment: unfortunately..Yes..working on it..will let you know