# How to download packages from github when a proxy is active

Tags: r, github, proxy, package

My employer recommends to use the following setting to download and install packages in RStudio:

1. Tools > Global options > Packages > unmark "use secure download method for HTTP"
2. Write the following in .Renviron:

> http_proxy=http://proxy.XXX.ch:8080/

> https_proxy=http://proxy.XXX.ch:8080/

This works for regular downloads such as:

```
install.packages("renv")
renv::install("pacman")
```

However, for packages on github I get the following error:

```
install_github('ropensci/tabulizerjars')


Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783686/solution-how-to-install-github-when-there-is-a-proxy) post list this possible solution:

```
set_config(
  use_proxy(url="18.91.12.23", port=8080, username="user",password="password")
)
```

I think the url should be `http://proxy.XXX.ch:8080/`
But I do not know what I sould use as username and password.
I also located the ***wpad.dat*** file, however I could not find any further useful information there.

**Update:**

As r2evans mentioned a possible workaround is to download the .ZIP files, from github, unzip them and locally install them using `devtools::install(..)` (also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213295/11482110))

Comment: Perhaps not the main question, but why is it okay for an employer to mandate that you not use secure browsing? Either wait, I don't think github allows http connections, and I don't think `remotes::install_github` makes it easy to change the scheme. If you also cannot use https on the shell prompt, and if you have a github ssh key, perhaps you can `git clone ssh://.../ropensci/tabulizerjars`?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. Very good point. I will check that. Would `git clone ssh:..` just download the package to the local machine? I tried to manually downlad the .ZIP files from github and used `devtools::install(path to ZIP)` to install them. This worked for `ropensci/tabulizerjars` but I got the HTTP code 407 error when I did this manual approach for `ropensci/tabulizer`.

Comment: yes, the intent was to allow you to `devtools::install(..)` on a local path

Comment: @r2evans I just found that there was an error in my code leading to the http error when manually installing `ropensci/tabulizerjars`. So your solution `devtools::install(..)` with a local path works. However, I would be vary glad to find a solution that works directly over github, since some packages might need many dependencies.